# How can I store and lookup a Delegate Method in a dictionary based on Type?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a an application with Multiple **DataGridViews**.  I want to run a similar event on all of them, to check if the Data has changed when a user is Done editing a cell or has selected a different cell.  To do that I've added a method to the **CellEndEdit** and **CellValidating** *events*.

I've abstracted out the code to where the my change check method signature looks like so:

```
ProcessIsChangedCheck<TypedTableBase<DataRow>, DataRow>
                     (dgv, validatingEventArgs.ColumnIndex,
                      validatingEventArgs.RowIndex,
                      getOriginal);
```

**getOriginal** is a delegate along the lines of `Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>`

The idea is I just want to add the same event to each table and have it lookup the **getOriginal** method based on the type of data the *DataGridView* is displaying.

I've tried the following Dictionary approach:

```
//private Dictionary<Type, Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>> _getOriginalLookup;
private Dictionary<Type, Func<Decimal, dynamic>> _getOriginalLookup;

private Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>> LookupGetOriginal(Type type)
{
   //lazy load the lookuo table
   if (null == _getOriginalLookup)
   {
      Dictionary<Type, Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>> orig =
                new Dictionary<Type, Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>>(3)
                    {
                       {
                          typeof (csedformsDataSet.AREARow),
                          //(Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>)
                          aREATableAdapter.GetAreaForID
                       },
                       {
                          typeof (csedformsDataSet.FIELDRow),
                          //(Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>)
                          fIELDTableAdapter.GetForFieldID
                       },
                       {
                          typeof (csedformsDataSet.PROMPTRow),
                          //(Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>)
                          pROMPTTableAdapter.GetByID
                       }
                    };
                       /*,
                       {
                          typeof (csedformsDataSet.DIARYRow),
                          //(Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>)
                          dIARYTableAdapter.GetByID
                       }*/

      _getOriginalLookup = orig;
   }
   return (Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>>) _getOriginalLookup[type];
}
```

However that leads to casting errors.

**NOTE:**
The methods each return a different type roughly
`NamedDataTable : TypedTableBase<NamedRow> where NamedRow : DataRow`

Form what I can tell the problem seems to stem from the nested types on **TypedTableBase**.

With a dictionary implementation I've described my Event handlers look like so:

```
private void CheckIfCellChanged(object sender, 
                                DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

   DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dgv.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;

   Func<Decimal, TypedTableBase<DataRow>> getOriginal =
   LookupGetOriginal(drv.Row.GetType());

   ProcessIsChangedCheck<TypedTableBase<DataRow>, DataRow>
                        (dgv, e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex,
                        getOriginal);

   Refresh();
}
```

So How can I properly define my dictionary so it will compile and I lookup and dynamically pass in the getOriginal method based on the data type of the DataGridView Data?

Comment: Why so convoluted?  Simply use the CellBeginEdit event to save the cell's Value property.

Comment: @HansPassant insightful Comments like that are why I include background info in my questions.  Thank you.

Comment: @HansPassant if you write that up as an Answer I'll accept it.  You were right, I was running down a rabbit hole when there was a much easier/simpler solution.